# Retrieving both JSON and PHP values from a function

Tags: php, json, laravel, vue.js

I'm using the `laravel-searchable` package from `Spatie` to help me with search functionality inside my `Laravel` application.

I have the following block of code inside my `SearchController.php` file:

```php
public function searchCategories(Request $request) {
    $results = (new Search())
        ->registerModel(Category::class, ['title', 'id'])
        ->search($request->input('query'));

    return response()->json($results);
}
```

The values are returned through a `vue.js` function with some help fom `axios`:

```
if(document.getElementById("search-all")) {
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#search-all',

        data() {
            return {
                query: null,
                results: [],
                isActive: false
            };

        },
        watch: {
            query(after, before) {
                this.searchAll();
                this.isActive = true;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            searchAll() {
                axios.get('/search', {params: {query: this.query}})
                    .then(response => this.results = response.data)
                    .catch(error => {
                    });
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Then I have form input that triggers the `vue.js` function and which retrieves `HTML` as follows:

```html
<div v-if="results.length > 0 && query" class="results" v-bind:class="{ show : isActive}">
    <div class="row main-row">
        <div v-for="result in results.slice(0,10)" :key="result.id" class="col-lg-6">
            <a :href="result.url">
                <div class="card main-card result-card course-card">
                    <div class="course-card-content">
                        <h6 v-text="result.title"> </h6>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>{{-- CARD END--}}
            </a>
        </div><!-- COL-4 END-->
    </div><!-- ROW END-->
</div><!-- OVERVIEW END-->
```

This is all working fine, the `JSON` is retrieved and displayed. However, I need some of the functionality in a `PHP` variable or I want to to be able to use the `JSON` data inside my `Blade` functions.

I have tried to return an array from my `searchCategories()` function like so:

```php
public function searchCategories(Request $request) {
    $results = (new Search())
        ->registerModel(Category::class, ['title'])
        ->search($request->input('query'));

    $res = response()->json($results);

    return array($results, $res);
}
```

However, I have no idea how to retrieve the `JSON` data now.

### Summary:

I would like to be able to use both the `PHP` variable and the `JSON` data that my function returns.

Example of the usage I have in mind: 
For instance, there's a background image inside my results, like so:

```html
<div class="course-image" style="background: url({{asset('./img/categories/ . $res->image_name')}});"></div>
```

This can ( as far as i know ) only be achieved by having access to the `PHP` variable besides the `JSON` data. Or being able to use this `JSON` data inside my `blade` `asset()` function.

Comment: That `{{` isn't JSON - that's twig syntax (or.. is it blade for Laravel?)

Comment: @treyBake You can use that syntax for both twig and blade.

Comment: Why not write the proper code to enhance the returned JSON such that it contains everything you need? I don't get from your code what you mean by "both JSON and PHP values", as the result should **always** be formed as JSON regardless whether the content comes directly from the datadase or from recomputed data

Comment: @Daan ahh, not used blade - thought it was more `@` based

Comment: @treyBake You can escape blade by using @{{ }}

Comment: Create another method which actually fetches the data and pass it the value of `$request->input('query')` from the above method.  Then you can then have another method which calls this new method with whatever you value for query you need.

Comment: @nico my Json does contain everything I need, I just don't know how to use it in my blade functions, as described in my last 2 paragraphs. For example: I have the results.image_name from my Json but I don't know how to use that in the blade asset() function.

Comment: I think there's a fundamental error in your plan: the JSON is generated on the server and sent to the browser to be evaluated there. The blade functions are also evaluated on the server. Usually, they have no access to any JSON results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error and people pointing me in the proper direction on here I found the solution:

I added an extra `img_path` var that holds the first part of the image path to my `vue.js` function:

```
data() {
      return {
          query: null,
          results: [],
          isActive: false,
          img_path: 'img/categories/'
      };

},
```

Then i retrieve it inside a `v-bind:style` with the output from the result, like so:

```
<div class="course-image" v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + img_path + result.image_name + ')' }"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

why not request the image name or all parameters that you need and make the rest on the js part i think it will be so easy if you do it like that.

```
public function searchCategories(Request $request) {
$results = (new Search())
    ->registerModel(Category::class, ['title', 'id', 'image_name'])
    ->search($request->input('query'));

return response()->json($results);
}
```

and on for other part like that

```
<div class="course-image" style="background: url({{asset('./img/categories/')}}result.image_name);">
```

i don't know vue.js but it suppose to work because blade will print the base path for the image and js will print the rest it should work you can try it

Comment: ok but if you have store image on the public folder just remove the first ./ yo get
url({{asset('img/categories/')}} iff this doesn't work for you either send me the path you see for the backgroud  url you can see it on the source code